# What is less sexual sounding alternative to "Long and hard"?

Tags: synonyms

Every time i say "Long and hard" in a sentence, i always find my self thinking about how dirty it sounds, and other people would probably point it out as well.

I was wondering if there's any less sexual sounding alternatives to them three words. For an examples i'd use it in things such as, i was thinking long and hard, i was working long and hard, etc.

Doesn't matter if the alternative is a single word, or multiple, i just wanted to avoid the whole string of words and say something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say 'I was working **[tirelessly](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tirelessly)**'

> untiring; indefatigable:

*Dictionary.com*

It implies both that you worked for a long period of time and that you worked hard.

Comment: But could that be uses for something like "I was thinking tirelessly" ?

Comment: No, @Lukaash, that would be awkward and odd, and *long and hard* goes with the verb *think* [more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think+long+and+hard%2Cwork+long+and+hard&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) than with *work* (or with *fight,* and that is true for base form and simple past both). But for that you could use a single verb to mean *think hard--ponder* or *cogitate* perhaps--and thus modify it only with *long* or *extensively.*

Answer (score 0):

I've thought the same thing and I usually end up using one of the following since they seem to indicate a time duration as well.

"Arduous" or "Grueling"

Answer (score 0):

You can say "I am burning the candle at both ends"

or

"I am going extra-mile"

or

"I am working my fingers to the bone"

or

"I am working my butt-off"